# IE11 keep aspect ratio for img with height: 100% width: auto

Tags: css

I have an image inside of a container that should be automatically sized according to the container size:

```css
container {
  height: 60px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="/logo.png" class="logo" />
</div>
```

The height is correctly restricted by the container, but the width remains the size of the actual image width. Is there some way to tell it that it needs to keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: This is suppose to work fine on IE11. Is there any other rules involved else where, ... maybe flex ? (can you updated in your snippet the link img src ? you can use for example: http://dummyimage.com/100x150 update the size to your logo's size , so everybody and yourself might see the issue live)

Comment: And I don't see no semi colons (`;`) after the css rules (eg. `height: 100%;`).